# I cannot acces S3 even if I am allowed to it

Tags: amazon-s3

I am using Amazon stuff. I have this IAM:

```
{
"Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "SSSSSS",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": [
        "s3:GetObject"
      ],
      "Resource": [
        "arn:aws:s3:::bucket1-name",
        "arn:aws:s3:::bucket1-name/*"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

I want to get an image from the bucket and I am getting the error `Access Denied`. What is the problem here?

Comment: did you use the same account to upload this image into bucket?

Comment: Yes, I have used the same things.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that the image I was trying to get was not on the Bucket. If I have tried to get an image that is on the specified bucket, it is not giving me the error of `Access Denied`. So, the problem seems to be that the Amazon is not making difference between `Access Denied` and `Object not found`.